# Color depending on value

Tags: php, css, colors

I use this code multiple times in my script. Is there a way to shorten this code? Thank you in advance.

```
if ($aUurverschil < 0){$avroegerkleur = "red";} 
if ($aUurverschil > 0){$avroegerkleur = "green";}
if ($aUurverschil == 0){$avroegerkleur = "#48f442";}

if ($bUurverschil < 0){$bvroegerkleur = "red";} 
if ($bUurverschil > 0){$bvroegerkleur = "green";}
if ($bUurverschil == 0){$bvroegerkleur = "#48f442";}
```

etc etc.

I use them in a div:

```
<div style="display:inline;color:<? echo $avroegerkleur;?>;">
```

Comment: You have duplicate conditions. As it currently stands, no color will ever be set to `green`.

Comment: As for the optimization, if the conditions are the same, put them in a function and reuse it.

Comment: If you "use this code multiple times"... Make it a function?

Comment: I have corrected it, thanks.

Comment: In what way do you "use this code multiple times"?  It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: do you mean you have these with a prefix of  a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,.....

Comment: @David, I mean: I have a lot of variables that I give a color in this way. That is a lot of reused code. I don't know how to put this in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can abstract this logic:

```
if ($bUurverschil < 0){$bvroegerkleur = "red";} 
if ($bUurverschil > 0){$bvroegerkleur = "green";}
if ($bUurverschil == 0){$bvroegerkleur = "#48f442";}
```

into a function, for example:

```
function getColor($uurverschil) {
  return ($uurverschil < 0 ? "red" :
         ($uurverschil > 0 ? "green" :
         ("#48f442")));
}
```

Then anywhere you want to use that logic, just invoke that function with the value you're examining:

```
<div style="display:inline;color:<? echo getColor($aUurverschil); ?>;">
```

Comment: This will always return "green"?... (unless it's 0)

Comment: That works perfect, thank you very much @David!!

Comment: FYI - you only needed parenthesis around the second ternary operator `$uurverschil < 0 ? "red" : ($uurverschil > 0 ? "green" : "#48f442")`